# How to merge multiple audio files together with ffmpeg lib?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, discord.js, stream

I have many audio files, and I want to merge them, but each audio file plays at a specific time, and the duration between them is in silent sound, and I specify the duration, as if I am making a timeline in the ffmpeg library
how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge all your audio file into one by using

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

const command = ffmpeg();

command
  .input('audio1.mp3')
  .input('audio2.mp3')
  .mergeToFile('merged.mp3', './');
```

This will merge all songs and create a new **MP3** file.